# IIS Import/Export Application is missing on Windows Server 2012

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

We've got a new Application Server and I have to set up the IIS.
Unfortunately, the `Import Application` of the `Default Web Site` is missing...
I couldn't find where I have to activate / install something to get these items...

Can you help me where to find this option to enable the Deployment-Category?

Thanks in advance

Comment: After installing Web Deployment tool on the server, a separate download, you will get the menu items.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get it working you can always do it with CMD:
Export:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list app "%WEBSITENAME%/%APPLICATION%" /config /xml > C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%WEBSITEXML%.xml
```

And for Import:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add app /in < C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\%WEBSITEXML%.xml
```

You can make your own small bat app out of this...

Comment: If you need batch app I can write complete code here.

Comment: Thanks for this. Super easy and saved me hours of clicking and comparing two IIS servers side by side.